# update query issue of GROUP BY sum() function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update, subquery

Here is the [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0648c/1) 
I am trying to use `sum()` function. It's working only `SELECT` query but it's give wrong value when I try this in subquery on `UPDATE` query.Here my `SELECT` query

```
SELECT 
  sum(i.pr_pur_cost_price*i.quantity) AS net_amount
FROM 
  product_purchases AS p
LEFT JOIN 
  product_purchase_item AS i
ON 
  p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
WHERE 
  p.insert_operation=48
GROUP BY 
  p.insert_operation
```

Here My update query

```
UPDATE 
  shop_balance AS s 
SET 
   s.shop_balance=(s.shop_balance-(
      SELECT 
         sum(i.pr_pur_cost_price*i.quantity) as net_amount 
      FROM 
         product_purchases AS p
      LEFT JOIN 
         product_purchase_item AS i
      ON
         p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
      WHERE 
         p.insert_operation=48
      GROUP BY 
         p.insert_operation
     )
   )
where s.shop_balance_id=n;
```

Why this wrong value in UPDATE query. is it problem for two columns in sum() function? or any best solution?

Comment: Could you perhaps show some sample data and desired (correct) result?

Comment: my first SELECT query return a FLOAT datatype suppose 2200. if my s.shop_balance is 2500. it should return 300. but it gives wrong value

Comment: `where s.shop_balance_id=n;` - Is "n" a valid shop_balance_id?

Comment: yea, it's any integer value

Comment: @coder. I don't see how that error is happening. Your code looks to be working correctly. Can you add some data on sqlfiddle to show the problem?

Comment: So in `WHERE` you're testing for equality `float` and `int`, right?

Comment: no `where s.shop_balance_id` is the primary id of shop balance. ok i'll show in sqlfiddle

Comment: oh @FilipeSilva I'm so confusing. it's working on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd55/1). but it's not working on my localhost. why I dont know

Comment: Your code looks to be good to work. You may have something strange on your existing script. Don't you have a trigger or something that might be updating the value on shop_balance?

Comment: yes, I was use trigger

Comment: You may want to check the trigger then, it's a very reasonable explanation to your problem

Comment: ok, thank you for your consult, I just already lost 3-4 hours. may be I'll find problem, note that may be I should use 'DOUBLE' for 'pr_pur_cost_price' because sqlfiddle alert me when i try up to thousands amount. I'll check now

Comment: Yes. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/628639/1385896 for a good discussion on data types for currency. But that isn't the reason for your original problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34939/discussion-between-coder-and-filipe-silva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the same issue?

[MYSQL Update using sum() result across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470041/mysql-update-using-sum-result-across-multiple-tables)

The update statement does not allow group by, would it be a problem if you just removed it.

I am sorry that I am not able to see if it would be a problem in your scenario, but I am not able to understand the need for it in the context of your update statement.

Can you just try removing them or adding them in a way that it does not form part of the actual update statement itself?

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd55/1) working. but working on my localhost

Comment: This isn't the case. He is doing what worked for the poster in the mentioned issue.

Comment: Once there is a filter to select only a specific insert operation will the group by make a difference at all, and in sqlfiddle, just to ensure clarity you set it to Mysql?

Comment: thank you very much @skv. and also sorry for let. I'm ensure that group by not working in `UPDATE` statement

Comment: oh I'm using trigger so don't worry, may be I am not miss behave on `UPDATE` statement