# MYSQL UPDATE TABLE ERRORS

Tags: mysql, sql

I want do some calculations for the column `total`
by adding the two marks columns for the specific
`std_id`.

**For example  `30+25=55`, total=55 for std_id 32**

```
+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+    
| std_id | course_id | marks | mp | subject        | total |    
+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+    
|     32 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |     0 |    
|     32 |        40 | 25.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |     0 |    
|     39 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |     0 |    
|     39 |        40 | 20.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |     0 |   
+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+
```

I tried something like

```
update student_reports 
set total= sum(marks) 
where std_id=std_id;
```

but does not work, ***any help is greatly appreciated especially one that does not require changing the table structure***

For the first table above, with a single course_id, the code
by GILEYS calculated the total perfectly

***update student_reports r, (
    select std_id, sum(marks) as total
    from student_reports 
    group by std_id
) t 
set r.total = t.total 
where r.std_id = t.std_id;***

My next question is what if i add another course_id value, to make it ***(40,43)*** to 
the table, how can i do the new totals

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

| std_id | course_id | marks | mp | subject        | total |

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

|     32 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |     0 |

|     32 |        40 | 25.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |     0 |

|     39 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |     0 |

|     39 |        40 | 20.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |     0 |

|     32 |        43 | 40.00 | 22 | Core Maths     |     0 |

|     32 |        43 | 20.00 | 12 | Core Maths     |     0 |

|     39 |        43 | 45.00 | 22 | Core Maths     |     0 |

|     39 |        43 | 40.00 | 12 | Core Maths     |     0 |

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

I tried something like

***update student_reports r, (select std_id,course_id,subject, sum(marks) 
as total from student_reports group by std_id) t set r.total = t.total 
where r.std_id = t.std_id AND r.course_id=t.course_id AND r.subject=t.subject;***

but is not giving out the totals as i would expert, please need
your help again

to achieve the desired results below

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

| std_id | course_id | marks | mp | subject        | total |

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

|     32 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |    55 |

|     32 |        40 | 25.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |    55 |

|     39 |        40 | 30.00 | 22 | Elective Maths |    50 |

|     39 |        40 | 20.00 | 12 | Elective Maths |    50 |

|     32 |        43 | 40.00 | 22 | Core Maths     |    60 |

|     32 |        43 | 20.00 | 12 | Core Maths     |    60 |

|     39 |        43 | 45.00 | 22 | Core Maths     |    95 |

|     39 |        43 | 40.00 | 12 | Core Maths     |    95 |

+--------+-----------+-------+----+----------------+-------+

Comment: You want to update any record in the table or just fetch the total marks of any student?

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653826/update-with-sum-in-mysql (but as you want only for one ID, it may work with a subquery)

Comment: @ Gmiley is there a code that will do the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update student_reports 
set total = (
    select sum(marks) 
    from student_reports 
    where std_id = 32
) 
where std_id = 32;
```

Or if you want the entire table updated:

```
    update student_reports 
    set total = t.total
    from (
        select std_id, sum(marks) as total
        from student_reports 
        group by std_id
    ) t
   where t.std_id = student_reports.std_id;
```

Edit, the above may not work on MySQL, you can try the following:

```
update student_reports r, (
    select std_id, sum(marks) as total
    from student_reports 
    group by std_id
) t 
set r.total = t.total 
where r.std_id = t.std_id;
```

Comment: I used your code as follows, hope its correct      **update student_reports set total = t.total from (select std_id, sum(marks) as total from student_reports group by std_id) t where t.std_id = student_reports.std_id;** but had an error as follows  **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select std_id, sum(marks) as total from student_reports' at line 1**

Comment: Updated answer. The one you tried may not be compatible with mysql, try the last one.

Comment: Thank you so so much GMILEY, your last code worked like a charm. Will get in touch if there are new developments, More "grease to your elbow"

Comment: My next question is what if i add another course_id value, to make it (40,43) to the table, how can i do the new totals

Comment: You would probably want to add a trigger to the table to update that column or change that column to a derived or calculated column if you are looking to have that field always up to date, otherwise you will need to run that script each time.

Answer (score 0):

Having a 'total' column might cause grief because it will become wrong as soon as new data is inserted for a given id. This query will give you the same result without needing to run an update every time you get new data. If you need it to act like a table you can look into [creating a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

```
SELECT t.std_id, t.course_id, t.marks, t.mp, t.subject, c.total
FROM student_reports AS t
JOIN (SELECT std_id, SUM(marks) AS total
      FROM student_reports
      GROUP BY std_id) AS c ON c.std_id = t.std_id
```

Comment: Your code works but did not update the values in the 'total' column, Thanks so much for your help, will contact when there are new developments

Comment: My next question is what if i add another course_id value, to make it (40,43) to the table, how can i do the new totals

Comment: That was kind of the point I was trying to make. If you have a totals column, it will be wrong when you add data. With a query (or view) it's always correct as of when you run the query.